# How to echo last query string in Phalcon?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phalcon

I have worked a lot on codeigniter. In codeigniter , if there is need to get query string that is executed last, we can get it using:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
exit;
```

But currently I am working on phalcon and I am just at beginner level in this framework. I am curious if there is a way to echo last query string in phalcon.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using Raw Queries

Let us have the following query:

```
$phql = 'UPDATE `news` SET `category_id` = 5 WHERE `id` = :id';
$this->db->execute($phql, ['id' => 1]);
```

We can get debug query info with the following methods:

```
print_r($this->db->getSQLStatement());
```

> UPDATE `news` SET `category_id` = 5 WHERE `id` = :id

```
print_r($this->db->getSqlVariables());
```

> Array (
>       [id] => 1 )

More info about DB methods you can find here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo.html

---

### Working with Models

Setting up your DB connection and profiler service:

```
use Phalcon\Db\Profiler as ProfilerDb;
use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as MysqlPdo;

$di->set('profiler', function () {
    return new ProfilerDb();
}, true);

$di->set('db', function () use ($di) {

    $eventsManager = new EventsManager();

    // Get a shared instance of the DbProfiler
    $profiler      = $di->getProfiler();

    // Listen all the database events
    $eventsManager->attach('db', function ($event, $connection) use ($profiler) {
        if ($event->getType() == 'beforeQuery') {
            $profiler->startProfile($connection->getSQLStatement());
        }

        if ($event->getType() == 'afterQuery') {
            $profiler->stopProfile();
        }
    });

    $connection = new MysqlPdo(
        array(
            "host"     => "localhost",
            "username" => "root",
            "password" => "secret",
            "dbname"   => "invo"
        )
    );

    // Assign the eventsManager to the db adapter instance
    $connection->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

    return $connection;
});
```

Using it to debug your Queries:

```
// Send some SQL statements to the database
Robots::find();
Robots::find(
    array(
        "order" => "name"
    )
);
Robots::find(
    array(
        "limit" => 30
    )
);

// Get the generated profiles from the profiler
$profiles = $di->get('profiler')->getProfiles();

foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
   echo "SQL Statement: ", $profile->getSQLStatement(), "\n";
   echo "Start Time: ", $profile->getInitialTime(), "\n";
   echo "Final Time: ", $profile->getFinalTime(), "\n";
   echo "Total Elapsed Time: ", $profile->getTotalElapsedSeconds(), "\n";
}
```

More info on Profiler service: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#profiling-sql-statements

---

### Phalcon Prophiler Widget

I'm using a lovely debug widget for Phalcon made by Fabian Fülling. You can check the repository here: https://github.com/fabfuel/prophiler A sample screen shot of the widget in action below:

[image]

Comment: I am at 
`return $this->_userEntriesEntries->find(array("conditions" => "FeaturedPost = 1 and FeaturedPostStatus = 1", "order" => "ID DESC", "limit" => 4));` how do i do now?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please read the short guide on how to set up it.

Comment: I am up-voting this answer, because it is far better than the one I posted. (**mine is dirty and for lazy folks**)

Comment: Is there a way to print queries after binding or to print the bind params

Answer (score 2):

If you are running queries directly on your model instance and you are lazy, you can also do it like this:

```
$result = $this->_userEntriesE‌​ntries->find(array("c‌​onditions" => "FeaturedPost = 1 and FeaturedPostStatus = 1", "order" => "ID DESC", "limit" => 4))

var_dump($result);
```

`var_dump` the result object of your query. Within the PDO dump you will notice a key named `_pdoStatement`. This is your generated SQL query.

*This is not the recommended way, just a dirty trick.*

Comment: Thanks, as beings lazy, thats what I was looking for. Thanks. 
@Timothy