# See raw SQL query with Phalcon\Mvc\Model

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm having a very simple query that doesn't seem to work for some reason - no error is displayed, but it doesn't seem to be executed, so I'm wondering if it's a wrongly (but syntatically correct) generated query. I'd like to see the generated query - the bad thing is that the getSql() method of the Query object ($this->_modelsManager->getLastQuery()->getSql())  seems to only work for Select statements (https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/query.zep#L3563).

The code in question is as follows:

```
return $this->_modelsManager->executeUpdate("UPDATE " . __CLASS__ . " 
                        SET
                                hitCount = IFNULL(hitCount, 0) + 1
                        WHERE
                                uniqueHash = :uniqueHash:
                ", ['uniqueHash' => $uniqueHash]);
```

I manually replaced the values with the values received in the function, i.e.

```
echo "UPDATE " . __CLASS__ . " 
                        SET
                                hitCount = IFNULL(hitCount, 0) + 1
                        WHERE
                                uniqueHash = ".$uniqueHash
```

and the generated query executes successfully in MySQL Workbench (I only had to replace the **CLASS** with actual table name)

The other strange thing is that if I do replace the table name it in the query itself, I'm getting a very strange error in the errorlog:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class My\\Model\\Counter
```

I guess this would be hard to debug without more data, but I decided I'd mention it. I'm ready to provide more information if needed and I'm open to any pointers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967900/how-to-echo-last-query-string-in-phalcon

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement the profiler!