# Benchmarking actions in Phalcon

Tags: php, apache, benchmarking, phalcon, apachebench

I have been developing an app, and believe some actions might be a bit slow in a real life escenario, so I wanted to benchmark different implementations against my test data (taking into account SQL queries, for instance!), but I don't really know how to approach this in a nice manner.

So, how are individual phalcon actions benchmarked?

Comment: Perhaps this question and answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967900/how-to-echo-last-query-string-in-phalcon/38968165 I'm talking about the Prophiler library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find easly profilers for phalcon on github.

Another more complex but perhaps harder to understand is to create xdebug profiler snapshot. But it will provide more accurate data and you can possibly find bottlenecks in any your code.

Comment: But as i already wrote - if you need more complex with more information then actually xdebug profiler snapshot is way to go, it will provide much more information.