# How to dump the query in Phalcon Framework using Model

Tags: database, phalcon, phalcon-orm

```
 $content = Content::findFirst([
   'conditions' => 'state = :state: AND URLid = :url: AND city = :city:',
   'bind'       => [
        'state' => $geodata_usstates->statecode,
        'url'   => $company,
        'city'  => $geodata_geocity->city
     ]
  ]);
```

I want to dump the query generated for this. If I were using Laravel, I would simply do

```
$content->toSql();
```

But here I'm using Phalcon. How can I achieve the same thing in Phalcon?

Comment: Hey, perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967900/how-to-echo-last-query-string-in-phalcon

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov no this is not really what I'm looking for. I have already tried that but the above link is not using models as I'm using.

Comment: Second section "Working with Models" is exactly models demo...

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov well not, it's not like I have been using the Models.

Answer (score 1):

Query is not available in your model. Query is build based on model using query builder, passed to Query instance and executed against your db connection.

What you could do is use the events manager and read using the db:beforeQuery event

Example here https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/18371/check-the-connection-before-querying-into-database

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can output the complete query, because it's a prepared query - thus the best you'd get is:

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE state = ? AND URLid = ? AND city = ? LIMIT 1
```

Personally, I don't bother trying to log queries in code.  I've enabled the query log on my MariaDB server, and just check the log. The query logged is guaranteed to be the query run.